# Swagger is not picking up ModelMetadataType attributes in the web interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a generated service contract class, that I frequently refresh, where I want to include `[Required]` and `[DefaultValue("abc")]` attributes on some of the contract methods.

My solution, to prevent my code from getting blown away each refresh, is to use `[ModelMetadataType]` attribute. It appears to be working, but the web front-end isn't showing the red `*` to indicate required?

You can see `aaa` gets defaulted, but the required indicator does not. If I leave the field blank and run it, it has a validation error.

[image]

**Generated contract class:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()] [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2010/01/datacontracts")]
public partial class CallContext
{
    public string Company {get; set;}
}
```

**My metadata class:**

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(MyCallContextMetadata))]
public partial class CallContext
{
}

internal class MyCallContextMetadata
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false)]
    [DefaultValue("aaa")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you receive the parameter in your bakend? Can you share the action method?

Comment: @Karney. sorry for the delay, I don't understand what that means. I'm new to ASP.net dev. I have an old `WCF` service I'm just trying to wrap so it'll be in JSON and have swagger docs, so I just did `Add Connected Service` and let it generate a data contract. The data contract changes frequently, so I have to keep right clicking and doing "Update WCF Web Service Reference...", so my solution was to create a metadata class that would persist and then I could update (regenerate) the contract classes and not worry about losing all of my attributes. What is the action method?